# How to use jQuery Tooltip?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, tooltip

I am using jQuery Tooltip and everything is working fine with one little problem: I am not seeing the arrow shape of the tooltip. Instead I am getting a square shape. I want to get the arrow shape pointing towards the TextBox. I got the following code from [here](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#custom-style) and everything looks okay when you look at this.

How can I get the arrow pointing shape? Here is my code:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
          $(function () {
              $(document).tooltip({
                  position: {
                      my: "center bottom-20",
                      at: "center top",
                      using: function (position, feedback) {
                          $(this).css(position);
                          $("<div>")
            .addClass("arrow")
            .addClass(feedback.vertical)
            .addClass(feedback.horizontal)
            .appendTo(this);
                      }
                  }
              });
          });
  </script>
  <style type="text/css">
  .ui-tooltip, .arrow:after {
    background: black;
    border: 2px solid white;
  }
  .ui-tooltip {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 20px;
    font: bold 14px "Helvetica Neue", Sans-Serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    box-shadow: 0 0 7px black;
  }
  .arrow {
    width: 70px;
    height: 16px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -35px;
    bottom: -16px;
  }
  .arrow.top {
    top: -16px;
    bottom: auto;
  }
  .arrow.left {
    left: 20%;
  }
  .arrow:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
    top: -20px;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    box-shadow: 6px 5px 9px -9px black;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    tranform: rotate(45deg);
  }
  .arrow.top:after {
    bottom: -20px;
    top: auto;
  }
  </style>
```

One thing to note is that I am using ASP.NET and I am getting red lines under these:

```
box-shadow:
tranform:
border-radius:
```

The error reads like this "[property] is not a known CSS property name" for each of the above properties.

Comment: You are getting red error line under those property because of your editor doesn't have CSS3 intellisense

Comment: What browser (including version) are you using?

Comment: i am just using development server which is using IE

Comment: Where are you seeing the CSS errors? Visual Studio?

Comment: it seems it works with chrome but not with IE.  how can i fix this to make sure the arrow works in all browser?  thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arrow's working for me, and i basically just copied and pasted your code with the UI's example code as the body. Here's a dumb question: you are loading jqueryUI css BEFORE your custom css, right? You also may want to move your custom js to the end of the body, just before the ending `</body>` tag, just make sure it's AFTER JQuery and JQuery UI. [Here's a link to the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tpressley1/SGfWU/).

```
<script>
      $(function () {
          $(document).tooltip({
              position: {
                  my: "center bottom-20",
                  at: "center top",
                  using: function (position, feedback) {
                      $(this).css(position);
                      $("<div>")
        .addClass("arrow")
        .addClass(feedback.vertical)
        .addClass(feedback.horizontal)
        .appendTo(this);
                  }
              }
          });
      });
</script>
</body>
```

**Edit:** Just for giggles, I did a jsfiddle to illustrate my so very poorly articulated suggestion. lol. it uses the image. it's not perfect, but you get the idea. [The image Tool pointer](http://jsfiddle.net/tpressley1/NnMK8/48/)!!

Hope all has been helpful.

Comment: i see it is browser issue if i use chrome then it will work but IE does not work in other words i don't get the arrow.  how do i fix this?

Comment: @moe Unfortunately, if it's not showing the arrow, it's likely because your version of IE doesn't support pseudo selectors. No good way around browser support, other than image replacement. you could always give .arrow a background image. my suggestion is do browser sniffing, Modernizr perhaps, and for browsers that dont support ::before and ::after, and add a no-psuedo class to the body. give the .arrow class a diamond-shape by doing  transparent corners on an image. you can then add class rules(e.g. no-pseudo.arrow.left) to put the diamond halfway out of the container, creating an arrow.

Comment: also, seems like way more trouble than it's worth. i'd just leave the arrowless tooltip alone, and the user would still have a richer experience, and would never know or care the arrow existed.

Answer (score 0):

I spent a few hours hacking the CSS to get this to work under IE 8.  The solution uses the triangle icon provided by jQuery UI Themes.  Please see this post for the answer:  [How do you make the arrows appear on the jQuery UI 1.10.2 Tooltips widget in IE 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17051908/how-do-you-make-the-arrows-appear-on-the-jquery-ui-1-10-2-tooltips-widget-in-ie/17069816#17069816)