# How do you make the arrows appear on the jQuery UI 1.10.2 Tooltips widget in IE 8?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer-8

I'm using jQuery 1.9.1 and Jquery UI 1.10.2 combined with the demo code shown on the jQuery UI site http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#custom-style.  The custom-style demo shows the arrow pointing downward under FireFox.  In IE 8, the same demo shows a rectangle without the arrow.  The Tipsy plugin works fine under IE 8 and renders the arrows correctly.  Has anyone had success with jQuery UI tooltips (and arrows) under IE 8?  I am not including code because it is on the jqueryui.com link shown above.  Please note, jsfiddle does not work on IE 8 either.  I am guessing this may be as simple as a .css fix.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to get the arrow working by using the jQuery UI icon png files in the CSS.  I also learned a little bit along the way.  The code following ui-icons_ is the color code.  My method of adding an arrow to the tooltips widget relies on a color match between the box and the arrow icon which limits your options (short of editing/creating a png file).  The sample code shown displays the arrow on the bottom of the tooltips box and uses the jQuery UI Start theme.

CSS:

```
.ui-tooltip {
    border:0px;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    color: white;
    font:  10px "Helvetica Neue", Sans-Serif bold;
    background: #f7a50d;
}
.arrow {
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -35px;
    bottom: -10px;
    background-image: url(../jQuery/Styles/start/images/ui-icons_f7a50d_256x240.png); 
    background-position: -64px -16px;
}
```

jQuery:

```
    jQuery(document).tooltip({
    position: {
        my: "center bottom-5",
        at: "center top",
        using: function (position, feedback) {
            $(this).css(position);
            $("<div>")
            .addClass("arrow")
            .addClass(feedback.vertical)
            .addClass(feedback.horizontal)
            .appendTo(this);
        }
    }
});
```